# Ternary expression in template arguments in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, compiler-errors, clang

Consider the following (artificial) example:

```
template <int N>
struct S {};

template <typename T>
S<1 ? 42 : 24> f() { return {}; }
```

Compiling it with MSVC 19 2017 (https://godbolt.org/g/K58FMr) gives a bunch of errors:

```
<source>(5): error C2059: syntax error: '<end Parse>'
<source>(5): error C2976: 'S': too few template arguments
<source>(2): note: see declaration of 'S'
<source>(5): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
<source>(5): error C2059: syntax error: '{'
<source>(5): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
<source>(5): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

while both clang and gcc compile it successfully. Is it a bug in MSVC or am I doing something wrong?

P.S. I know that `1 ? 42 : 24` can be simplified. It is here specifically to demonstrate the problem on a small reproducible case.

Comment: MSVC isn't even C99-conforming, so one shouldn't be too surprised.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Just what exactly does a compiler's C conformance have to do with compilation errors for valid but esoteric template code?

Answer (score 2):

MSVC bugs out when it parses it. It's all valid C++. You can give it a helping hand however, by adding parentheses:

```
template <int N>
struct S {};

template <typename T>
S< (1 ? 42 : 24) > f() { return {}; }
```

<kbd>[**See it live**](https://godbolt.org/g/HoAEtH)</kbd>